# Reorder UITableViewCells and objects in CoreData

Tags: sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I'm using Core Data in an app.  I have a `UITableView` and am using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

These are my entities and attributes:

[image: Entities]

My setup looks like this:

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Timer")
    let fetchSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orderBy", ascending: true)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "timerWorkout", workout)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [fetchSort]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unable to perform fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

I have workout items that have a list of timers on them.  Users can add timers and I'd like for them to be able to order them in whatever way they'd like.  So that an order can be specified, I added the orderBy attribute.  When a new item is added, I use this code for determining the value of orderBy:

```
    if let timer = vc?.timer {
        timer.orderBy = workout.workoutTimers?.count
        workout.mutableSetValueForKey("workoutTimers").addObject(timer)

        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print("Unable to add timer.")
        }
    }
```

It works for what it is.  The problem that I run in to is I would like to reorder the items by allowing the user to move them in the list.  Moving the `UITableViewCell` items is easy, but I have not been able to figure out how to reorder them in the data set.  This is some of what I've attempted.  The commented out rows are various things that I've tried.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //let orderedSet = workout.valueForKey("workoutTimers") as? NSMutableOrderedSet
    //myObject.valueForKeyPath("subObjects") as NSMutableSet
    //let orderedSet = fetchedResultsController.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
    //let orderedSet: NSMutableOrderedSet = (fetchedResultsController?.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("Timer"))!
    //let orderedSet: NSMutableOrderedSet = (workout.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("workoutTimers"))
    //let orderedSet = workout.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("workoutTimers")
    let orderedSet = workout.workoutTimers?.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("orderBy")
    orderedSet.exchangeObjectAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    do {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Unable to reorder.")
    }
}
```

So far, nothing works.  The exception that I'm mostly getting is:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key.

Can anyone offer some assistance on what I am missing with this?

Edit:

After reading the comments on the question, this is what I came up with.  It seems to work, and is much cleaner.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let items: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!) {
        if let sourceItem = items.objectAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row) as? Timer {
            items.removeObject(sourceItem)
            items.insertObject(sourceItem, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

            var index = 0

            for item in items {
                (item as? Timer)?.orderBy = index
                index += 1
            }

            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {
                print("Unable to reorder.")
            }

            timersTable.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your relationship ordered? You can't really mix an ordered relationship with an order value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Really you should not be trying to do anything with an ordered relationship. You should create a loop over the indexes of the item move and add and subtract to reorganise the values. So the item that moved has the size of the move added or subtracted and everything else has one added or subtracted.

Comment: I think that I understand what you're getting at.  I updated my question with a solution that seems to work correctly.